# Sound doesn't work in Lubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Tags: sound, lubuntu

I have just made a fresh install of Lubuntu using this image: lubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso . Everything works fine, except the audio, there is no sound at all.

There is a speaker volume icon in the system tray.

The computer is new (and the monitor btw), and the audio has not been tested yet.

AlsaMixer reports two sound adapters: ATI R6xx HDMI and Realtek ALC897. The computer is connected to the monitor via standard audio cable, AND through HDMI over KVM switch.

The mainboard is MSI A520M-A PRO, and the CPU is AMD Ryzen 5 5600G.

Thanks in advance!

Additional data: I tried this:

```
sudo lshw -C sound
```

and got the following:

```
  *-multimedia:0
   description: Audio device
   product: Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:30:00.1
   logical name: card0
   logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
   logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:73 memory:fcc88000-fcc8bfff
  *-multimedia:1
       description: Audio device
       product: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.6
       bus info: pci@0000:30:00.6
       logical name: card1
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D2c
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:74 memory:fcc80000-fcc87fff
```

I think the problem is up to choosing the appropriate audio driver, but I can't manage it.

Comment: I succeded to get the sound through a HDMI connection. I just used PulseAudio Volume Control for settings. However, there is still no sound through the audio cable.